# Make the data from the second column stay at the second column

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm making a form using reportlab and its in two columns. The second columns is just a copy of the first column.

I used Frame() function to create two columns and I used a Spacer() function to separate the original form from the copied form into two columns.

My expected result is to make the data from the second column stay in place. But the result that I'm getting is when the data from the first columns gets shorter the second columns starts shifting up and moves to the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your question correct, the problem is that you use a spacer to control the contents' visual placement in two columns/frames. By this, you see it as a single long column split in two, meanwhile you need to see it as two separate columns (two separate frames).

Therefore you will get greater control if you end the first frame (with FrameBreak() before start filling the other and only use the spacer to control any visual design within the same frame.

Tools you need to be aware of are:
FrameBreak(), if you search for it you will find many code examples.

e.g. you fill frame 1 with with 10 lines of text, then you insert a FramBreak() and instruct the script to start filling the second column.

Another tool you should be aware of is the settings used e.g for BaseDocTemplate:

allowSplitting: If set to 1, flowables (eg, paragraphs) may be split across frames or pages. If 0, you force content into the same frame. (default: 1, disabled with 0).

Comment: Let me know if you need some code examples to complete the suggested answer

Comment: great, glad I could help. please mark as an Answer and uptick it so I get some cookie points on the stats, thanks